# one of my friend want to use my developer account to submit app

Tags: iphone, ios, codesign

One of my friend want to use my developer account to submit app, because he do not want o apply for a new account.

And I do not want to get his source codes.
Is there a way he can compile his app project with my account codesign in his xcode?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was similar to "develop my apps on two iMacs".

1. Create a new RSA key pair, use this new key pair to get your new certificates and provisioning files from iOS Dev Center.
2. Ask your friend to import the new RSA private key on his own iMac, and then install the new certificates and provisioning files.
3. He can then sign his code with your newly-created provisioning file on his own iMac, and give the final binary to you without you actually seeing the code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would think he would need to mess with the Keychain on his Mac.

I'd personally not recommend it and tell him to get his own account or send you the source   :-)

Answer (score 0):

The keychains as mentioned by diwup, will not mess with any other existing keychains on his mac