# If I develop an iPhone app for a friend's business and that friend doesn't have a Mac, how can I upload the app under his company name?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I don't want to release it under my own membership profile - but they don't have a Mac. Is there a way to sign the binary with their profile and upload it without messing with my own profiles? I opened App Uploader and it automatically checked my account on Apple for possible Apps to upload. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613648/one-of-my-friend-want-to-use-my-developer-account-to-submit-app/) for signing your friend's binary with a different provisioning file on the same Mac.
- As for the Application Loader problem, see the screenshot below. Yes, you need to run the setup wizard again to log out your own account and re-sign in with your friend's account.

[image]